# Graphing $-\log_2x$ , $\log_2(-x)$, and $-\log_2(-x)$ by hand.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Trying to graph $-\log_2x$ , $\log_2(-x)$, and $-\log_2(-x)$.

I don't understand which one reflects over the x axis, the y axis?

Answer (score 1):

First sketch the graph of $y=\log_2 x$.

Now imagine how you would use this graph to obtain the graph of $y=-\log_2 x$.  You'd take every point on the graph of $y=\log_2 x$ and switch the sign of the $y$ coordinate. This amounts to reflecting the point on  the graph of $y=\log_2 x$  through the $x$-axis.

So the graph of $y=-\log_2 x$ is  the graph of $y=\log_2 x$ reflected through the $x$-axis.

Similar considerations should convince you that the graph of $y=\log_2(-x)$ is the graph of $y=\log_2 x$ reflected through the $y$-axis.

Note for your third function, you do both reflections.

Answer (score 0):

$f(-x)$ is said to be a mirror reflection of the function $f(x)$ over the $y$-axis.

$-f(x)$ is said to be a mirror reflection of the function $f(x)$ over the $x$-axis.

I hope this may be useful to you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

$y=f(-x)$ and $y=f(x)$ are symmetrical with $y$-axis.

$-y=f(x)$ and $y=f(x)$ are symmetrical with $x$-axis.

Then, note that 
$$y=-\log_2x\iff -y=\log_2x$$
$$y=\log_2(-x)$$
$$y=-\log_2(-x)\iff -y=\log_2(-x),$$
and that $-y=\log_2(-x)$ and $y=\log_2(-x)$ are symmetrical with $x$-axis.